# mapbox и окно-подсказка, раскрывающееся вниз при нажатии мыши

Tags: mapbox

Кто-нибудь знает, как в mapbox gl сделать следующее?

На данный момент при наведении указателя мыши на маркер карты у меня появляется окно-подсказка

```html
var infobox = new mapboxgl.Popup({
            closeButton: false,
            closeOnClick: false
        })

 map.on('mousemove', function(e) {
   var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point, {
                layers: [‘layer’]
            });
         
   map.getCanvas().style.cursor = (features.length) ? 'pointer' : '';

            if (!features.length) {
                infobox.remove();
                return;
            }

            var feature = features[0];
            infobox.setLngLat(feature.geometry.coordinates)
                .setHTML(‘Bla bla bla…’)
                .addTo(map);
        });
```

Вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы при клике на окно-подсказку оно раскрывалось вниз и показывало дополнительный контент?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот таким css можно это сделать:

```
div.mapboxgl-popup-content:active{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
}
```

```js
let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', 
    style: {
        "version": 8,
        "sources": {
            "simple-tiles": {
                "type": "raster",
                "tiles": [
                    "https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                    "https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                ],
                "tileSize": 256
            }
        },
        "layers": [{
            "id": "simple-tiles",
            "type": "raster",
            "source": "simple-tiles",
            "minzoom": 0,
            "maxzoom": 22
        }]
    },
    center: [30.3, 60], 
    zoom: 12 
});

var infobox = new mapboxgl.Popup({
    closeButton: false,
    closeOnClick: false
})

 infobox.setLngLat([30.3, 60])
         .setHTML('click on me')
         .addTo(map);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#map {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

div.mapboxgl-popup-content:active{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<div id='map'></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за помощь @Stranger in the Q!